# Java ellipsis(...) wraps the Object Array in another parent Object

Tags: java, arrays, format, ellipsis

I am trying to print some logs using the following code snippet. This does not produce the desired output.

```
Object[] arguments = new Object[] {"Atul", "Kumar"};
Object[] parent = new Object[1];
parent[0] = arguments;
String log = MessageFormat.format("Error : {0}, due to {1}", parent[0]);
System.out.print(log);
//prints : Error : [Ljava.lang.Object;@54bedef2, due to {1}
```

However, the following code works fine.

```
Object[] arguments = new Object[] {"Atul", "Kumar"};
String log = MessageFormat.format("Error : {0}, due to {1}", arguments);
System.out.print(log);
//prints : Error : Atul, due to Kumar
```

I would think that `parent[0]` also represents `arguments Object []`.
Why is the first code snippet not working? Please suggest.

While debugging, I have seen that `MessageFormat.format(String pattern, Object ... arguments)` wraps the Obeject[] in a parent Object[] of length 1.

Comment: Keep in mind that the compiler always only deals with declared types, and not with runtime types. In your first example, the type of `parent[0]` is `Object` (and not `Object[]`). And according to the [JLS §15.12.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.2), this is then encapsulated in new array when being the argument for a variable arity method.

Answer (score 2):

In the first one, `parent` stores `Object`, so when giving `parent[0]` that is **one** Object, one element formatted in `{0}`, and the `toString` of an array is used

In the second one, what is given to `format` is an `Object[]` so it can be expanded at multiple values with the varags `...`

---

To get the first one working, you need to explicitly tell **what** is stored in each box, here `Object[]`

```
Object[] arguments = new Object[]{"Atul", "Kumar"};
Object[][] parent = new Object[1][];
parent[0] = arguments;
String log = MessageFormat.format("Error : {0}, due to {1}", parent[0]);
System.out.println(log);

// Error : Atul, due to Kumar
```

Comment: You could cast to `Object[]` as well. But I think the question is why java isn't spreading the array as vargs input without this hint.